# Reset DataGridView blank row if user clicks in that row and takes focus off that row

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, focus, reset

If a user clicks the blank row at the bottom of a DataGridView and moves focus away from the DataGridView, the row click in now is in a state that indicates a change is made to that row.

Is it possible to tell the DataGridView to un-mark this row as being changed?

Is it possible to reset this row when focus is off the DataGridView?

We are using the following event handler to alert the user if the Invoiced On is left blank:

```
Private Sub dataGridViewPayments_CellValidating(ByVal sender As Object, _
ByVal e As DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs) _
Handles DataGridViewPayments.CellValidating

    Dim headerText As String = _
        DataGridViewPayments.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).HeaderText

    ' Validate the Invoiced On cell and display the error if it's empty.
    '-------------------------------------------------------------------
    If (String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.FormattedValue.ToString()) And
        headerText.Equals("Invoiced On")) Then

        DataGridViewPayments.Rows(e.RowIndex).ErrorText = _
            "Please enter an Inoiced On date."

        e.Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Looks like we need a way to stop this from executing if the user simply clicks in the grid then clicks somewhere else in the form.

Comment: The default behaviour for the dgv is to only create a new row when you start editing it. just clicking on the row should not do anything unless you have modified the begin edit behaviour. Is it after you have begun editing that you get the row marked as to be added? Either way, this is not going to be easy to fix. Might be better to look at row validation or default values for new rows so that you ensure rows are always ready to save once the grid loses focus.

Comment: Thanks David for the reply. I believe I need to alter the CellValidating event handler. I'm including the coding in that handler as part of this post. Can you show me what to add to this handler to not validate if the user just simply clicks in the grid then tries to click somewhere else on the form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
Private Sub dg_CellValidating(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs) Handles dg.CellValidating
    Dim headerText As String = dg.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).HeaderText

    'Try this --------------------------------------------------------------
    Dim vClicked As Boolean = False
    If (Control.MouseButtons And MouseButtons.Left) = MouseButtons.Left Then
        vClicked = True
    End If
    '-----------------------------------------------------------------------

    'Validate the Invoiced On cell and display the error if it's empty.
    'And put vClicked here
    If Not vClicked AndAlso (String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.FormattedValue.ToString()) And headerText.Equals("Invoiced On")) Then

        dg.Rows(e.RowIndex).ErrorText = "Please enter an Inoiced On date."

        e.Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Please, let me know if it helped. =)